# MSSQL How to check if at least 1 substring exists in string?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TabSTR
(
   ID INT,
   SBSTR VARCHAR(1000)
)

CREATE TABLE TabSubSTR
(
   ID INT,
   SubSBSTR VARCHAR(100)
)
```

And I need to get all rows from 1st table TabSTR  where at list one SubSBSTR exists in SBSTR.

```
 SELECT * FROM TabSTR A
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TabSubSTR B WHERE A.SBSTR LIKE '%' + B.SubSBSTR + '%')
```

Test data:

1st table:

```
INSERT INTO TabSTR VALUES (1, 'This is first row')
INSERT INTO TabSTR VALUES (2, 'This is second row')
INSERT INTO TabSTR VALUES (3, 'Third row is here')
INSERT INTO TabSTR VALUES (4, 'Another third row')
INSERT INTO TabSTR VALUES (5, 'Hello word')
INSERT INTO TabSTR VALUES (6, 'Hello')
```

2nd table:

```
INSERT INTO TabSubSTR VALUES (1, '1st')
INSERT INTO TabSubSTR VALUES (2, 'second')
INSERT INTO TabSubSTR VALUES (3, 'third')
INSERT INTO TabSubSTR VALUES (4, 'four')
INSERT INTO TabSubSTR VALUES (5, '5th')
INSERT INTO TabSubSTR VALUES (6, '6th')
INSERT INTO TabSubSTR VALUES (7, 'ord')
```

Result data:

```
2,'This is second row'
4,'Another third row'
5,'Hello word'
```

The problem - LIKE operator is very slow when there are thousands of rows to match
I tried also full-text search here but it is also very slow when TabSubSTR rows count ~ 200k

Maybe smb has any other ideas?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try : `SELECT * FROM TabSTR A
 INNER JOIN TabSubSTR B
 ON A.SBSTR LIKE '%' + B.SubSBSTR + '%'`

Comment: @KillerQueen The same problem :( very slow

Comment: I tried that and found it was roughly 3 times slower than the `WHERE EXISTS` method.

Comment: So there is no relationship between the tables AT ALL? Well, then it will be slow as it will effectively cross join the rows between the tables and then scan. It may be time to step back to think about your ultimate goal and reconsider the decisions leading to this implementation.

Comment: Why not `SELECT * 
FROM 
TabSTR, TabSubSTR
WHERE TabSTR.SBSTR LIKE '%' + TabSubSTR.SubSBSTR + '%' `

Comment: @SMor Yes, you are right. There are no other references between these tables. I'm thinking about other variants just now

Comment: Cross join for your pleasure `SELECT * 
FROM 
TabSTR CROSS JOIN TabSubSTR
WHERE CHARINDEX(TabSubSTR.SubSBSTR, TabSTR.SBSTR) > 0`

Comment: If you actually need this then look at https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search but why are you doing this? If `SBSTR` is a delimited list of some sort don't do that

Comment: @Nando I have tested both variants, and they are much slower then EXISTS

Comment: @MartinSmith I have below data:

1st table:

This is first row
This is second row
Third row is here
Another third row
Hello word
Hello

2nd table:

1st
second
third
four
5th
6th
word


Result data:

This is second row
Another third row
Hello word

Comment: We are professionals and can't think like that but... why is it a problem the execution time ? Do you msut have the result as soon as possible ? Otherwise put it in a job agent, a SSIS, the night is so long ... be careful, someone can ear us

Comment: Try identities and foreign kies. That's good too.

Comment: @Nando It is important for project purpose. I provided only test sample. Identities and FK can not help in text search

Comment: Well, maybe could you considere a search engine like Elastic. At work I use Exalead. This kind of products looking for quickly strings in strings.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: curious if the search is looking for whole words or partial?  If whole words you could split the first table into individual words and then do the join to TabSubSTR.  Add sample data and expected output to your question, that would helpful.

Comment: @TimMylott It searches for partial word